# How to clean view object?

Tags: java, android, memory-management, view

I'm developing an application where I have one activity and many view subclasses.
When I need to change the view I'm calling a loading screen (which is another view class) and load the new view on a separate thread (using runnable) and when it's ready I'm setting the view with `SetContentView` function.

Now the problem that I face is that I run out of memory. Because every view has it's own list of objects that it loads.

Now my question is, how do I free memory, so I won't run into the `out of memory` exception?

P.S.
I have tried nulling the old view and recycling all the bitmaps that it has and then calling for `System.gc()` though no luck so far.

Comment: What's the amount of memory your JVM has access to?

Comment: @RaptorDotCpp, well the heap size is restricted to 32mb, If I exceed this amount I get out of memory error. I need somehow to kill the previous view (free memory) and put the new view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using intents to display the views in different classes.

Comment: Hmmm on second thought, maybe you are right, I'll try to use an intent and see if it'll help me

Comment: Well I've solved this problem with two activities and a separate process (`android:process`) for each one. One activity plays the role of a loader, while the other displays the view. So, when I'm in view and need to change it to other view, I send an intent with the new view to load (identifier) and process id of the activity that's showing the view. Then in my loader-activity I kill the process with the activity containing view and re-initiate it.

Answer (score 0):

Do a thread.interrupt () when the view is not in focus

Comment: @Jack Mwangi, where do I put it? and how will it help me? I don't need to stop my `Runnable`, but free memory of the previous view.

Answer (score 0):

was thinking you could try to split the views into different activity classes.then you can start an activity with startActivityforResult(intent) and when you aee done with the view,just call finish().it will get remove the resources from memory.

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to test both your ideas and come back with results.